# Fusion Tables Filtering/query

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-fusion-tables

I'm using greet searchable map template with fusion tables by Derek Eder. I can connect the script to my fusion table and showing my projects on map successfully but when I'm trying to filter from a type column using checkboxs, the data on map not changing. Can any one help me?
Here's my website: http://bu.sixtag.com and if you look at the resource there's a js file name maps_lib.js that there's my setting.

Answer (score 1):

I just took a quick look at your code to see if I could offer any assistance as I too am working through some of Derek Eder's wonderful fusion table searchable template examples. What I did see was errors in your code, specifically

```
Invalid row index 4. Should be in the range [0-3].
```

If I were you I would make a point of familiarizing myself with [console.log()](http://getfirebug.com/logging) as it's really useful to help self-diagnose your code first before posting up help etc.

Good luck!!